# Styling the <hr /> element

Tags: css

I am trying to make my  `<hr />` (hr) element pinkish, and am using the following css rule for this:

```
hr {height: 1px; color: #ed1d61;background-color: #ed1d61;
}
```

But there is still a black line showing through it.

(here is a look at it on the site that I am making: http://www.yemon.org/ , its the only horizontal line in the design.

How do i get the line uniform pink?

Comment: The `hr` listens best to the `border` property.

Comment: I thought hr was deprecated when geocities closed shop.

Comment: Check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6382036/937891 to a possible duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
hr {
    height: 1px;
    color: #ed1d61;
    background: #ed1d61;
    font-size: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Looking at your page, I think this would look best:

```
hr {height: 2px;
    background-color: #ed1d61;
    border:none
}
```

A demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krejX/).

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the border color property: border-color:#ed1d61;

Answer (score 5):

The hr element is made of border so a simple border:none and you'll get rid of the excess.

Then you simply have to play on your height to make it as thick as you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    margin: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
hr{
    background-color: #ed1d61;
    border-width: 0;
    /*change your size in this place*/
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
sadf
```