# Changing the color of an hr element

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of my `hr` tag using CSS. The code I've tried below doesn't seem to work:

```css
hr {
    color: #123455;
}
```

Comment: chrome not working background-color too not working for me

Comment: Okay, just in case anyone wants to test, here's a fiddle I've got going so far, http://jsfiddle.net/TGtSd/9/...

Comment: try `hr{display:block; height: 1px; border:0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }`

Answer (score 1309, accepted):

I think you should use `border-color` instead of `color`, if your intention is to change the color of the line produced by `<hr>` tag.

Although, it has been pointed in comments that, if you change the size of your line, border will still be as wide as you specified in styles, and line will be filled with the default color (which is not a desired effect most of the time). So it seems like in this case you would also need to specify `background-color` (as suggested by @Ibu).

**HTML 5 Boilerplate** project in its default stylesheet [specifies](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/a7820f12647fdb93b19340391ac4c60de15352ce/dist/css/style.css#L37-L48) the following rule:

```css
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**An article** titled [“12 Little-Known CSS Facts”](http://www.sitepoint.com/12-little-known-css-facts/), published recently by SitePoint, mentions that `<hr>` can set its `border-color` to its parent's `color` if you specify `hr { border-color: inherit }`.

Comment: The problem with border-color is that if you make the hr larger, it just colors the border, http://jsfiddle.net/TGtSd/9/...

Comment: @Anton that's not what I was referring to about the size of the hr...if you increase the height, and you only use border-color, you'll get a rectangle with a colored border, but the inside won't be colored...

Comment: Why even bother with the border at all? Why not just give it a background-color and be done with it? Edit: nvm, I didn't see the answer on browser compatibility.

Comment: @anton many thanks!  I was really banging my head against the wall on this one :-O `border-color: inherit;` also worked well for me.

Comment: In chrome v109, when I changed `border-color` alone it mixed black in with my color. I had to define the full `border`

Comment: background color seems to work now in Chrome and Firefox and Safari. I'd suggest `background-color: red;` as the accepted answer, the closest I think from the current answers was https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399500/10467153

Answer (score 149):

- `border-color` works in **Chrome** and **Safari**.
- `background-color` works in Firefox and Opera.
- `color` works in **IE7+**.

Comment: If we wish our site to be seen on all browsers, should we use them all?

Comment: `border-color` **doesn't** work on Chrome. Try setting it to white on white background. These two will work: Either **1)** `color:white; border-style:solid;` or **2)** `border-color:white; border-style:solid;`.

Comment: @Pacerier yes it does. Might need to specify a style and/or width

Comment: the information re. IE (at least) is incorrect.  'border-color' works fine in IE; 'color' does not (IE11)

Answer (score 142):

I think this can be useful. this was simple CSS selector.

```css
hr { background-color: red; height: 1px; border: 0; }
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: This definitely worked for me in chrome desktop: <style>
hr { background-color: red; height: 1px; border: 0; }
</style>
<hr>

Comment: Works for me in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Will need to add a width value if you're doing this in a column-direction flex container.

Answer (score 57):

```css
hr {
    height: 1px;
    color: #123455;
    background-color: #123455;
    border: none;
}
```

Doing it this way allows you to change the height if needed. Good luck. Source: [How To Style HR with CSS](https://www.alexanderonlinemedia.com/how-to-style-with-css/)

Answer (score 33):

Tested in Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari.

```css
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPSjU/).

Answer (score 18):

This will keep the Horizontal Rule 1px thick while also changing the color of it:

```css
hr {
  height: 0; 
  border: 0; 
  border-top: 1px solid #083972; 
}
```

Comment: Best answer here.  Setting the height to 0px and adding the border doe not make the hr 2 px wide.  Great call !!

Answer (score 15):

Only border-top with color is enough to make the line in different color.

```css
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: it has strange dots to the right and left of the line

Answer (score 12):

After reading all the answers here, and seeing the complexity described, I set upon a small diversion for experimenting with HR. And, the conclusion is that you can throw out most of the monkeypatched CSS you wrote, read this small [primer](https://jsfiddle.net/RedDevil/ds20fjo6/) and just use these two lines of pure CSS:

```css
hr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: cornflowerblue; /* or whatever */
}
```

That is **ALL** you need to style your HRs.

- Works cross-browser, cross-device, cross-os, cross-english-channel, cross-ages.
- No *"I think this will work..."*, *"you need to keep Safari/IE in mind..."*, etc.
- no extra css - no `height`, `width`, `background-color`, `color`, etc. involved.

Just bulletproof colourful HRs. It's *that* simple<sup>TM</sup>.

---

Bonus: To give the HR some height `H`, just set the `border-width` as `H/2`.

Comment: I took a bet each way:
```
  hr {
    border-top: 1px solid purple;
    border-color: purple;
    background-color: purple;
    color: purple;
  }
~~~

Comment: 2022: this is the answer that works, others either aren't or overcomplicated

Comment: And you can use `border-color: currentColor`, so both `color` and `border-color` work.

Comment: Great job, works on all browsers!

Answer (score 10):

```css
hr {
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```css
hr {
  background-color: #123455;
}
```

The background is the one you should try to change.

You can also work with the borders color. I am not sure; I think there are cross-browser issues with this. You should test it in different browsers.

Comment: I tried it in Firefox 5 Beta, IE 9, Chrome, Opera, and Safari...you're good, they all work ;)

Comment: @kool, which part doesnt work? background-color? or border-color? i just tested border-color: blue; and it worked in chrome

Comment: [border-color] works in Chrome. [background-color] does not. I would vote down if I had enough rep.

Comment: It was a bit of a surprise for me, but border-color didn't work in my case, but background did, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is the most effective approach:

```
<hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">
```

Or if you prefer doing it on all hr elements write this on you CSS:

```css
hr {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add bootstrap bg class like

```
<hr class="bg-light" />
```

Comment: Turns out this was the perfect answer for me, although I've done it in the past by adjusting the border. BTW, Bootstrap 4 does it this way: `.bg-light { background-color: #f8f9fa !important; }`

Comment: `.bg-dark` is another good option, for sites with a black or dark background.

Answer (score 6):

Some browsers use the `color` attribute and some use the `background-color` attribute. To be safe:

```css
hr {
  color: #color;
  background-color: #color;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if u use css class then it will be taken by all 'hr' tags , but if u want for a particular 'hr' use the below code i.e, inline css

```
<hr style="color:#99CC99" />
```

if it's not working in chrome try below code:

```
<hr color="red" />
```

Answer (score 5):

It's simple and my favorite.

```
<hr style="background-color: #dd3333" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set border-width to 0; It works well in Firefox and Chrome.

```css
hr {
  clear: both;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  height: 1px;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr />
This is a test
<hr />
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm testing on IE, Firefox and Chrome May 2015 and this works best with the current versions.  It centers the HR and makes it 70% wide:

```css
hr.light { 
    width:70%; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    border:0px none white; 
    border-top:1px solid lightgrey; 
}
```

```html
<hr class="light" />
```

Comment: this exacly what I was looking for. My mistake was I was adding a space between hr and class in css definition ( hr .light {} )

Answer (score 2):

Since i don't have reputation to comment, i will give here a few ideas.

if you want a css variable height, take off all borders and give a background color.

```
    hr{
        height:2px;
        border:0px;
        background:green;
        margin:0px;/*sometimes useful*/
    }
    /*Doesn't work in ie7 and below and in Quirks Mode*/
```

if you want simply a style that you know that will work (example: to replace a border in a ::before element for most email clients or

```
    hr{
        height:0px;
        border:0px;
        border-top:2px solid blue;
        margin:0px;/*useful sometimes*/
    }
```

In both ways, if you set a width, it will always have it's size.

No need to set `display:block;` for this.

To be totally safe, you can mix both, 'cause some browsers can get confused with `height:0px;`:

```
    hr{
        height:1px;
        border:0px;
        background:blue;
        border-top:1px solid blue;
        margin:0px;/*useful sometimes*/
    }
```

With this method you can be sure that it will have at least 2px in height.

It's a line more, but safety is safety.

This is the method you should use to be compatible with almost everything.

Remember: Gmail only detects inline css and some email clients may not support backgrounds or borders. If one fails, you will still have a 1px line. Better than nothing.

In the worst cases, you can try to add `color:blue;`.

In the worst of the worst cases, you can try to use a `<font color="blue"></font>` tag and put your precious `<hr/>` tag inside it. It will inherit the `<font></font>` tag color.

With this method, you **WILL** want to do like this: `<hr width="50" align="left"/>`.

Example:

```
    <span>
        awhieugfrafgtgtfhjjygfjyjg
        <font color="#42B3E5"><hr width="50" align="left"/></font>
    </span>
    <!--Doesn't work in ie7 and below and in Quirks Mode-->
```

Here is a link for you to check: http://jsfiddle.net/sna2D/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to make a line with a different color, example would be like that:

```
border-left: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
border-right: medium none;
border-width: medium medium medium 2px;
border-style: none none none solid;
border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color rgb(216, 216, 216);
```

that code will display vertical grey line.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answers setting border-top, but they are somehow still a little off in Chrome...
BUT if I set `border-top: 1px solid black;` and `border-bottom: 0px;` I end up with a *truly* single line (that also works fine with higher thickness).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am new in HTML, CSS and in Java but I tried my way which worked for me in all browsers. I have used JS instead of CSS *which doesn't work with some browsers*.

First of all I have given `id="myHR"` to HR element and used it in Java Script. 
Here is the Code.

```
x = document.getElementById("myHR");
y = x.style.width = "600px";
y = x.style.color = "white";
y = x.style.height = "2px";
y = x.style.border = "none";
y = x.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Code Works For older IE
2. Tried For Many Colors

   ```
   <hr color="black">
   <hr color="blue">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `<hr noshade>` tag and go to your css file and add :

```css
hr {
    border-top:0;
    color: #123455;
}
```

```html
<hr noshade />
This s a test
<hr noshade />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using font colours to modify horizontal rules makes them more flexible and easy to use.

The `color` property isn't inherited by default, so the following needs to be added to hr's to allow color inheritance:

```css
/* allow hr to inherit color */
hr { border: 1px solid;}

/* reusable colour modifier */
.fc_-alpha { color: crimson;}
```

```html
normal hr:

<hr>

hr with <span class="fc_-alpha">colour modifier</span>:

<hr class="fc_-alpha">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```css
hr {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<hr />
This s a test
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you can’t just set the color of a horizontal line with CSS like you would anything else. 
First of all, Internet Explorer needs the color in your CSS to read like this:

“color: #123455”

But Opera and Mozilla needs the color in your CSS to read like this:

“background-color: #123455”

So, you will need to add both options to your CSS.

Next, you will need to give the horizontal line some dimensions or it will default to the standard height, width and color set by your browser. 
Here is a sample code of what your CSS should look like to get the blue horizontal line.

```
hr {
border: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #123455;
background-color: #123455;
height: 5px;
}
```

Or you could just add the style to your HTML page directly when you insert a horizontal line, like this:

```
<hr style="background:#123455" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I took a bet each way:

```css
hr {
  border-top: 1px solid purple;
  border-color: purple;
  background-color: purple;
  color: purple;
}
```