# CSS change color of hr tag

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS : change color of hr tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/css-change-color-of-hr-tag)

how do you change the color of an hr tag? i looked it up and found this, but it didnt work..

```
hr{
    color:#CCC;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39):

Style the border.

```
hr{
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: this will return a line in the height of 2px. This is due to the fact that it has a  top and a bottom border the simple solution is to set 0.5px or to set the information in border-top.

Comment: @ElishaSterngold Good point! I think just setting the border-top is better. I'm usually cautious around setting subpixels because then it's really on the browser to interpret how to render it.

Answer (score 8):

Just change the border color. For instance, this HTML produces a red horizontal row.

```
<hr style="border: 1px solid #f00" />​
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the color of it's border

Answer (score 1):

probably the best way to add a custom style to show an horizontal rule in a *crossbrowser* way is to style instead a border-top of the following element (or the border-bottom of previous one)

Another solution is to style :after or :before psuedoelements of one of the `<hr>` adjacent/sibling elements

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<hr noshade="noshade" />
```

as your hr tag, and then use the same CSS as you have already.

EDIT:

You can also add

```
border: 1px solid #CCC;
```

to your CSS.