# What is the default color of an <hr>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Google was no luck, and also existing `hr` color questions, resulting in how to change the `hr` color

I want to create a `border` with the same color as the default `<hr>` color, but I don't know what color is it exactly.

Anyone knows?

p.s. - I know how to change the color of hr tag.. I want to find out what it is before I change it

Comment: Why not style the `<hr>` instead - that way you control both colors. As for defaults - these would be browser dependent.

Comment: this depends on browser (and OS?)...

Comment: Yeah, the "default color" is passed around browser by browser and mobile by mobile so there is no definite answer

Comment: On some browsers (e.g Chrome), it's actually 2 colours anyway!

Comment: why did not use CSS to style?

Comment: can I do it in js? find the hr color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS : change color of hr tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/css-change-color-of-hr-tag)

Comment: So resume: you should not even try this, because very likely that this default color is different for different platforms. In order to make your design consistent you should choose some style (say, color `gray`) and use it as your default, and not rely on browser defaults.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The color of the horizontal ruler depends on the browser, but you can get the color of the `hr` element like following:

```
el = document.querySelector("hr");
color = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("border-top-color");
console.log(color);
```

Note however, that often the `border-style` is inset, so the color you get might differ from the "real" value you see on the screen. You either want to:

- give your border the same border-style as the `hr`
- set the border-style of the `hr` element to `solid` like I did in the demo to get the "real" color
- get the border-style of the `hr`-element to and adapt your color accordingly (might be tricky and browserdependent to compute)

See a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hxnq/3) which demonstrates getting the according color.

Comment: "Note however, that often, the `border-style` is inset, so the color might differ from the "real" value." - indeed. Screenshot here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lyqcc.png

Answer (score 3):

The color is browser/implementation dependent, so knowing the color is not possible.

Instead you can define the color of the `<hr>` element as you like using CSS:

```css
hr {
    color: red;
}
```

Now you know that the color is red!

**Update:** As it seems that depending on the browser one needs to use `color` or `background-color` (see comments). It seems sensible to use both in your CSS:

```css
hr {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Almost: `background-color`. `hr` usually doesn't have text content.

Comment: well Veger, Opera has a marketshare of 4? percent. So better test in other browsers... hr depends on border-color by default.

Comment: `color` doesn't work in Chrome, `background-color` does though.

Comment: @Christoph the fiddle is also showing a red line in FireFox... I cannot test IE as I do not use Windows, but I guess Chrome is being different? I guess your best bet is to both use `color` and `background-color` to support all? browsers...

Answer (score 3):

w3 does not define a default color for the hr element (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), html5 default stylesheet is not confirmed yet afaik but should not change this fact.

As a result, each browser is free to apply its own defaults.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's OS (or even device) dependent --- so there's no such thing as "default HR color".

Answer (score 1):

Note that some browsers don't render `<hr>`s as a one-colour line.

Here's a zoomed-in screenshot of the left-hand end of an `<hr>` in Chrome 24 on Windows on a white background:

[image]

So you've got two colours to choose from there.

Comment: unfortunately the returned value still is treated as one solid color, regardless of the side of the border.

Comment: @Christoph: indeed. I was more questioning the premise of the original question than actually answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Use both `color` and `background-color`

```
<hr />

hr {
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #f00;  
}
```

Working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/D2UaZ/1/

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to change an `<hr>`'s colour.

Comment: As other has said, the color of `<hr />` is browser dependent, so knowing the color is not possible

Comment: Sure, but you're still not answering the OP's question. The OP said "I want to create a border with the same color as the default <hr> color". Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I updated code it should be work. thanks for showing that

Comment: I think the OP means that the border will be on another element, not the `<hr>`.

Answer (score 0):

The default color of hr is black color

Answer (score 0):

It is **#eee** on Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure the exact color of the hr tag but the CSS code below will change the color to the color you choose.

```
hr { display: block; height: 1px;
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: shamelessly stolen from html5boilerplate and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6382036/1047823), btw. not my downvote.

Comment: @MattCain you are wrong... hr gets it's color from the border property.