# PHP: for-loops and if-statement

Tags: php, for-loop

I am currently studying a beginning PHP programming class and I need some assistance with one assignment I'm trying to solve.  The assignment is to create a form where the user can enter a positive integer.  Then, use a “for” loop to display that amount of horizontal lines created by the "hr" tag [Hint: `<hr size=1 width=50% color='black'>`]. Finally, use an if statement to perform “modulus” calculation. When the counter in the “for” loop is an even number set the width of the horizontal line to 50%; otherwise, set the width of the horizontal line to 100%.

Here's the code I have come up with thus far:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) { // if the form is filled out
$integer = $_POST["pi"];

$i = $integer;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $integer; $i++) {
if ($i % 2) { // modulus operator
echo "<hr size=1 width=50% color='black'>";
} else {
echo "<hr size=1 width=100% color='red'>";
}

}
}
else { // otherwise display the form
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Enter a <i>Positive Integer</i>:
<input type="text" name="pi" size=5>
<input type="submit" value="Check"></form></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

I can't post an image yet, but the sample output should be a 50% black horizontal rule, followed by a 100% red horizontal rule, until the integer entered is reached. In between each hr seems to have some spacing.

Comment: Try to format your code better for easier readability and therefore better quality.

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: See my answer, you just need to remove the `$i = $integer;` line

Comment: HTML attributes should be Strings in quotes `width='50%'` and the like. You should use CSS to style your Elements, anyways.

Comment: If you dont like spaces between HR elements - use margin and padding CSS attributes

Comment: You need to compare the % of the number to 0. See my answer.

Comment: Also, you contradict yourself, you say that an even number should output an `<hr>` tag 100% width followed by an odd number `<hr>` tag at 50% width but the colours you have stated along with the widths don't match up.

Comment: Oh, this is silly. The output of the code posted is exactly what the poster states SHOULD be output (50% black, then 100% red, repeating)... which is, oddly enough, not what the problem states the output should be (odd lines should be 100%, even should be 50%). At any rate, it all seems to work just fine.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Like I mentioned, I am new to this. In retrospect, the original code I posted did work, but the issue related to the redundancy of the $i = $integer line. The assignment would not be accepted with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$i = $integer;
```

...is redundant, as soon as you say `for($i = ...`, $i will be overwritten. In your case, so it should be. Take that line out to start with.

Second, I think the problem you're having is that your lines aren't showing as black or red. Reason is that `color` is a **font attribute** and you should look at this post to find out how to change your color:
[Changing the color of an hr element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element)

I suggest using `class='black'` and `class='red'` in your PHP and setting classes up in your CSS.

Comment: I'm using Safari and the color attribute works fine. Might not be the case with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are assigning $i equal to the variable $integer, therefore they are the same value.

```
    <?php
if ($_POST)
{ // if the form is filled out
    $integer = $_POST["pi"];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $integer; $i++)
    {
        if ($i % 2 ===0)
        { // modulus operator
            echo "<hr size=1 width=50% color='black'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<hr size=1 width=100% color='red'>";
        }
    }
}
else
{ // otherwise display the form
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Enter a <i>Positive Integer</i>:
<input type="text" name="pi" size=5>
<input type="submit" value="Check"></form></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: huh? makes no difference.. he's doing `$i = $integer` not `$integer = $i` which would (probably) have thrown an error anyway as it's a null-value...

Comment: of course `$i = $integer` is unneccessary but removing it won't change anything, as `$i` is reassigned in `for ($i = 1; $i <= $integer; $i++)`

Comment: see http://dev.michaelnorris.co.uk/so.php this is what the OP is asking for and this is the code displayed above.

Comment: The OP wants a `<hr>` tag spanning 100% followed by a `<hr>` tag spanning 50% repeated until the number that was submitted is reached. That is exactly what my code does.

Comment: Yes. You can try my code for yourself/see for yourself if you follow the link I posted above.

Comment: nice, think you just scored this guy a pass on his PHP paper!  =)

Comment: The original suggestion of removing the $i = $integer worked.  what I need is is the `<hr>` tag black spanning 50% followed by another `<hr>` tag red spanning 100%.

Comment: Removing `$i = $integer` makes no difference. And I tested your code and it already does what you describe?

Comment: The comparison to 0 does.

Comment: Not really, 0 == false

Comment: @mike When I remove the `===0` from your code above, I get the result I am looking for.  I want `<hr size=1 width=50% color='black'>` followed by `<hr size=1 width=100% color='red'>` until the integer entered is reached.

Comment: YES and what is your problem? Please, I don't understand.

Comment: @Colandus I apologize for the confusion.  Like I mentioned, I am new to this.  In retrospect, the original code I posted did work, but the issue related to the redundancy of the `$i = $integer` line. The assignment would not be accepted with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what the problem is. If the issue is that your HR elements have spaces between them, then removing the default margin will help (at least in Firefox, I'm not sure if all browsers use the same rendering rules on HR).

```
<hr size="1" width=50% color='black' style="margin:0;" />
<hr size="1" width=100% color='red' style="margin:0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS code to formatting all hr elements

```
<style type="text/css">
hr {margin: 0px auto 0px auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: The OP is not asking about styling the `<hr>` tags.

Comment: So what's he asking? His code is running just fine and quoting him "In between each hr seems to have some spacing", I assume it's his problem?