# How to change color of <hr/> element?

Tags: html, css, colors

I tried all ways to change color of `<hr/>`:

```
hr{
   border-color: yellow;
   background-color:  yellow;
   color: yellow;
  }
```

but it appears like this in both Chrome and FF:

[image: y]

How can I change its color to pure yellow?

Comment: Some further context would be helpful. Can you show us some HTML and CSS code so we can be sure of everything going on within your page?

Comment: @TylerH thanks! but it seems answer was too easy! just `border:0` !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the color of an hr element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-an-hr-element)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give `hr` a style with:

```
hr{
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

or

```
border:1px solid yellow;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBuQj/)

You need to get rid of the `border` or change the `border`'s properties for it work.

From [@Darko Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32943/darko-z) in the comments:

> In many browsers the default style for `HR` is to add some sort of shading to the `border` so this comes out as dirty #whateverColourYouWant. To get rid of it, setting border explicitly (and not just `border-color`) is necessary.

Comment: this is correct. In many browsers the default style for HR is to add some sort of shading to the border so this comes out as dirty #whateverColourYouWant. To get rid of it, setting border explicitly (and not just border-color) is necessary

Comment: ^ This information belongs in the answer. Is it in the HTML spec?

Comment: @TylerH this border is added by the browsers default style (kind of like default fonts, padding, margin etc) so it's not a part of the HTML spec. Just a thing that browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of your horizontal rule, in your `<hr/>` tag, type the html attribute `color=""`. Then you can go ahead giving it the desired color.