# How to draw a line with color in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

This may be a simplest thing for lot of people, but I'm struggling with it. 
I'd like to draw a line with color using html tag "hr"
This is what I have tried so far in ui.R file :

```
HTML("<hr color='purple' >")
HTML('<hr color="purple" >')
hr( color="purple" )
```

None of them worked - any suggestions please?

Comment: The [hr element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) doesn't have a `color` attribute. Try getting your tool to generate HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shiny exposes a lot of control over the look and feel of the application, but it happens that the color of `hr` isn't one of of them. So you'd need to dig down into CSS to control the appearance of the element. You can do this by using `includeCSS` in Shiny to add a stylesheet that you can use to control the look of your app. The easiest way, however, would likely just be to add the CSS onto your `hr` element directly.

```
HTML('<hr style="color: purple;">')
```

(EDIT) Note that, while this would work for most elements, `hr` don't respect the `color` property. `hr`s behave strangely: [Changing the color of an hr element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element)

Here you're modifying the CSS `color` property of your `hr` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color

Also note that you can use `hr(style="...")` instead of constructing the raw HTML, if you prefer. I find that constructing everything with Shiny tags makes the code a little easier to read in most cases, but YMMV.

Comment: I just tried with your suggestion and it is still not adding color to the line. I'm using Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m. Do you think it has anything to do with it?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited. These comments are true for most elements, but `hr`s are weird. You just need to find the right CSS to style an `hr`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element

Comment: Thanks Jeff - so, this is one of those holes with chrome. I'm good with border color for now for the line.

Comment: Combining elements of the above and below answers, this works in R Shiny version 1.2.0: `hr(style="border-color: purple")`.  Using just `color` as opposed to `border-color` didn't work on my end.

Answer (score 25):

It took a little bit of quick digging/reading into the answers and comments here, but, summarizing, this looks to work (I tested on Mac Chrome, Safari, and Firefox):

```
tags$hr(style="border-color: purple;")
```

You can use `HTML()`, too, if desired, but might as well stick with the [Shiny tags](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html), IMHO.