# Horizontal Rule hr() in R Shiny Sidebar

Tags: css, r, shiny

You can normally make a horizontal rule under UI elements with `hr()` when using `fluidRow()` in Shiny, but you can't do it in a `sideBarPanel()` under text. How can I make a horizontal rule, or something else like it, to divide text and UI elements in my sidebar?

Comment: Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659365/how-to-draw-a-line-with-color-in-shiny-application/41683366#41683366) will do: `tags$hr(style="border-color: black;")`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In general the line is visible, but with very low contrast to the background.
To make the line more visible you can modify the CSS code by including the following in the ui part:

```
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("hr {border-top: 1px solid #000000;}"))
  ),
```

with `tags$style(HTML(...))` you can include CSS in your app. The html tag for the line is `hr`. And the remaining parameter indicate specification of line choice, width, color, etc.

For a full working example see below:

```
library(shiny)
    
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("hr {border-top: 1px solid #000000;}"))
  ),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         "text",
         hr(),
         uiOutput("out")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("bins",
                "Number of bins:",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update 12.2020:**
Comment from David Ranzolin, see comment section.

> You can also pass a style argument to hr() directly, e.g.: `hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;")`

Comment: I see the problem. `hr()` creates a rule in a very light gray which is difficult to see against the gray of the sidebar. Is there a way to change its color?

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much.

Comment: You can also pass a style argument to hr() directly, e.g.: hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;")

Comment: very good point, i added it to the answer.