# How display a colored line in html?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm unable to use the style-color for tag "hr". Could someone help me me to display a colored line on the my jsp page using html?

Comment: <hr style="color: '#FF0000';"> this is what I tried foremost.

Comment: hr doesnt use color, it uses border-color

Comment: <hr style="border-color: #660000;">

Comment: @madforstrength     I had added the single quotes too for which it dint work. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`<hr>` doesnt use color, it uses `border-color`

Comment: Thanks..It worked with border-color and without single quotes.

Comment: should be backround-color

Answer (score 5):

You can apply border-color instead of color

```
<style>
hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
border-color:red;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<hr size="20" color="blue">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<hr style="height:1px;border-top:1px solid #f00" />
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
hr:first-child{color:red;}
hr:nth-child(2){color:yellow;}
hr:last-of-type{color:blue;}
```

```html
<hr><hr><hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<HR COLOR="green" WIDTH="60%">` works in IE, firefox, and chrome according to my own tests and [htmlgoodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479441#how)

If you want to add color using CSS then use `border-color` as can be shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

If you want good arguments for one over the other read this dated but [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element).

Answer (score 1):

```
<hr color="yellow"  width="100%" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hr {display: block; height:1px; float:left; border-bottom:1px solid #444444; }
```

Use this in ur css..