# How to make horizontal rule not stretch over?

Tags: html, css

I figured out how to get it to not stretch over the left side by using margin-left but when I try to get the right side by using margin-right it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this in CSS?
Here's what I got..

HTML

```
<div class="Heading">Painting</div>
<hr draggable="auto" color="#FB2529">
```

CSS

```
hr { color:#FB2529;
width:100%;
margin-top:-15px;
margin-left:29%;
height:.2px;
}
```

Comment: So do you want the HR to start 29% from the left side of the content region and extend to the right of the content region but no further? That might not be the best way to accomplish the task you're trying to do, but if that is the best route, you probably want the width to be 100% - 29% = 71%.

Comment: I might suggest a couple of other changes: remove the `color` attribute from your HTML tag (it's redundant and it's been removed from HTML spec anyway); and don't make the height a fraction of pixels, since it really can't be less than 1 pixel tall.

Comment: Well wait what's the best way? and yea I want it to start at 29%

Comment: ohhh okay and oh that makes since I'm still learning this stuff

Comment: Okay so when I remove the    color attribute from the HTML part it doesn't show up anymore

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response: you probably want to use the `border-color` property instead of `color` in the CSS. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6382036/546657

Comment: It's okay and thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by adjusting the `width` property in your css.. `margin-left` and `margin-right` should also be relative to the `width`..

when you adjust the margin in the left, the `width` is still 100% in the page and so, the right overflows...

to fix that, I suggest using this:

```
hr {  
   color:#FB2529;
   width:98%;
   margin-top:-15px;
   margin-left:1%;
   margin-right: 1%;
   height:.2px;
}
```

as you can see the sum of `width`, `margin-left`, and `margin-right` totals to 100% representing the width of the area.. if you want to set it instead in pixels, you can.. however, you should know the specific width in pixels also..