# Unstyling <hr> when it's wrapped in a div

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a div that wraps around my `<footer>` tag. In the div is an `<hr>`, which needs to be in the div to have the positioning properties applied. However, it also carries over the coloring of the links in my footer. I don't want the `<hr>` to be the same color as the links. Is there any way to "escape" this or change the property.

I tried `<hr style="color: black;">` but that didn't change anything. If you have any input on how to change the properties despite the set CSS in the div, I would greatly appreciate it.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o6vmz7t5/1/

HTML

```
<div id="footer_style">  
<hr>    
<footer>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
  <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
  <a href="">Create Account</a>
</footer>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer_style {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#footer_style a {
  color: #f2f0e1;
}

#footer_style a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the color of a hr element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hr tags simply have a border-top applied on them

override the hr as below

```
#footer_style hr {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer_style hr {
   background-color: black;
   height:1px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6vmz7t5/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, it had me struggling for a minute. Apparently since the *hr* has no height and you cant see its internal "fill",  affecting the color does nothing.

What you actually see is the border, so using `border-color` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code I have try this code. Using this code solve your problem.

```
  border-color: red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead Using the color: black;

Try using in this way

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
```

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/o6vmz7t5/3/)