# How to style up a hr tag

Tags: html, css, styling

I would like to style up a `<hr />` tag but can't seem to find an answer online anywhere that works.

I want to change the color and thickness if this is possible? I am able to change the length of it easy but that seems to be all that works so far.

Or is there an alternative to a hr tag that I can use?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the color of a hr element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
hr{
   border: none;
   height: 10px;
   background: #ccc;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nft4oeab/5/)**

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can change color by the attributes.

```
<hr color="red" size="10px">
```

Tested out here : 
    https://jsfiddle.net/8wevdosq/

Comment: Works but these attributes are deprecated in HTML5

Comment: yupe. since other answers was with css. i provided html ways.

Answer (score 0):

The `hr` is a border, so you just have to style the border in your CSS:

```
hr {
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/69vyr4h0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you styled class then you need to write "." over there if you styled id then you have to type "#" over there but if you style tag then just write tag name
Like...

```
hr{
     height:2px;
     background:yellow;
     border:0;
 }
```

Run Snippet code for more...

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Designing HR - Horizontal Row </title>
    <style>
      hr{
        height:2px;
        background:yellow;
        border:0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>
```