# How to set background-color on <hr> tag?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `hr` tag element not setting to green as coded below?

```css
hr {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: Have you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the color of a hr element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-a-hr-element)

Comment: Josh appears to be correct. The black you see with a default `hr` is its border not its background, you need to set `border-color`. Only if you give your `hr` a height property will the background become visible and necessitate the setting of `background-color`

Comment: by default browser rendering, `hr` tag gets it's color from `border-bottom-color` property of `CSS`. You can overwrite it by targeting the `border-color` property. And it even works if you just give a `color` property to `hr` tag, as `border-color` by-default gets `inherited` from `text-color`.

Answer (score 4):

The backround-color just sets background for hr by applying inline style we can make it easier.
https://jsbin.com/wuvolojuzu/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <hr color="red" width="100%" />
  <p>Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided *will* set the background colour correctly. However, the `<hr>` tag doesn't have a visible background, so it won't appear to do anything. What you probably instead want is to change its **color**:

```
hr {
   color: #00ff00;
}
```

That will make the `<hr>` line green.

If it doesn't, there's probably another element with more [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). In that case, you have a number of options:

1) Add more specificity to the `hr` selector.

2) Set the colour as `!important`:

```
hr {
   color: #00ff00 !important;
}
```

3) Set the background colour inline:

```
<hr color="#00ff00" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't set `background-color` for `hr` tag. This is an empty element. It must have start tag, but must not have an end tag. `hr` Only accept `color` property. For example:

```
<hr color="#00ff00" />
```

> Default `hr` value:

```
margin: 7px or 8px /*depend on box-modeling. */
border: 1px inset #000;
display: block;
/* No height */
```

> Standard use:

```
margin-top: 10px; /* You can change margin height */
margin-bottom: 10px; /* You can change margin height */
border: 0; /* or border-top: 5px solid #00ff00 */
border-width: 5px 0 0 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #00ff00;
```

```css
hr{
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help.