# How to change <hr> tag color inside form tag?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have to use `<hr>` tag inside form, but I can't change **color** of it. In usual `<div>` I can change color for that tag in CSS but when I put it inside `<form>` - CSS doesn't work and whole properties of `<hr>` are set default. Someone know why?.

.EDIT

Yes, I use bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
            <form id="form">
                <div class="user-info row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input required class="form-control" type="text"
                               placeholder="Name...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input required class="form-control" type="text"
                               placeholder="Email...">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h6>
                    Shopping information:
                </h6>

                <hr/>

                <div class="shopping-info">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Continue"
                       class="btn my-btn btn-block">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You perhaps have a reset stylesheet or use bootstrap? Show us the form, CSS and possible frameworks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the color of an hr element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-an-hr-element)

Answer (score 2):

Set `border-color` of the `<hr>` tag.

```css
form hr {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  This is form with an underline
  <hr>
</form>
```

Comment: Try in a style sheet instead of inline like OP asked

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your CSS and HTML code with us?

Properties of an hr tags are (or just default properties):

```
hr {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-image: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE -moz-use-text-color #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  margin: 18px 0;
}
```

You can use the border property to style a hr element like this:

```
/* Red border */
hr.new1 {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

/* Dashed red border */
hr.new2 {
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
}

/* Dotted red border */
hr.new3 {
  border-top: 1px dotted red;
}

/* Thick red border */
hr.new4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Large rounded green border */
hr.new5 {
  border: 10px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

For more info about the hr tag please check [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp)