# the element <hr/> styling isn't working in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, styling, horizontal-line

I am trying to style a  `<hr />` and I want to colorize it with red color, but it's not working !

This is my CSS code

```
hr {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

btw the `margin-bottom` worked!

I tried also to style it frim inspect Chrome and didn't work.
and here it is my hr.

[image: hr run on browser]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the color of an hr element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-an-hr-element)

Comment: are there any rules that override the current one?

Comment: I tried to give it an id but still isn' working .

Comment: it seems like my hr element has a space inside it like a rectangle . Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Color property is not affect hr tag.

- You can use background-color property. (for Opera, Chrome, Edge)
- You can use border-color property. (for Opera,Chrome, Edge, Firefox)

Comment: if it seems like rectangle you can use border-top: 1px solid red;

Comment: ok bro I tried  background-color property , it kinda worked 
thanks